# How can I get property reference from an class reference or generic type?

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I'm trying to replace assign() method with a niceAssign():

```
    class Builder<T : Any>(val kClass: KClass<T>) {
        fun <K> assign(prop: KProperty1<T, K>, value: K): Builder<T> = TODO("doing other stuff here")
        fun <K> niceAssign(call: KClass<T>.() -> Pair<KProperty1<T, K>, K>) : Builder<T> {
            val (prop, value) = call(kClass)
            return assign(prop, value)
        }
    }

    val builder = Builder(Data::class)
    builder.assign(Data::someProperty, "some value") // (1)
    builder.niceAssign { ::someProperty to "some value" } // (2)
```

Since builder object is generified with Data class, I don't really need to explicitly indicate Data class while passing a property reference. Assign method already knows which class that property belongs to. So I don't want write "Data::" every time in assign method (like in code (1)), but I want to pass "Data::" as a receiver property for niceAssign param, so I could reference ::someProperty from "this" object.

This code snippet doesn't work because I'm passing KClass as a receiver, and KClass doesn't have property references of T.
So, is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass property reference to a higher-order function, then it should be a function with a `T` as a receiver.

In the described case it need to be:

```kotlin
fun <K> niceAssign(call: T.() -> Pair<KProperty0<K>, K>) : Builder<T> {
...
}
```

But to "unpack" passed to `niceAssign` arguments (so that they could be passed further to `assign` function) you will need an instance of `T`, like:

```kotlin
val (prop, value) = call(kClass.createInstance())
```

Also result couldn't be passed to `assign` method as is, since `prop` parameter type won't match, so this approach will require some additional code rework.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I also thought about it.
But there is a problem, you have to create an instance of T manually before using that constructor. For arbitrary class (with non-null non-default fields) you can't call nor kClass.objectInstance neither kClass.createInstance(). So, the only way is to pass a reference object to Builder constructor, but it's a really strange way to handle that problem.